# Terminate http request from IP layer using golang

Tags: http, go, tcp

I am making an http post request to a server using golang. Suppose the server is currently turned off (Means the machine on which the server runs is turned off) then the request is stuck at the IP layer. So my program execution is unable to proceed further. It is unable to proceed to the Application layer. So is there any way in golang to stop this. 
I am using the following code.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewReader(b))
       if err != nil {
               return errors.Wrap(err, "new request error")
       }
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
       if err != nil {
               return errors.Wrap(err, "http request error")
       }
       defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Is there anything that can be added to this, to terminate the request if it doesn't find anything from the IP layer.

Comment: Well, the HTTO request will fail and the error will be one from package net indicating that dial failed. So: No, there is nothing to add: It already "terminates" the request if it doesnt find anything on the IP layer? Could you be more specific what doesn't work with the code shown?

Comment: I am sending a packet to an apache server and i expect to receive an ACK within 2-3 seconds. But the http request is unable to process within that time.

Comment: But my http request is stuck in the ip layer with a searching process that exceeds my ACK time. Is there any feature or API for fire and forget in http to implement directly. (Without using any channeling mechanism)

Comment: Okay. You need a http.Transport and fill in DialContext. Also take a look at package net. Please update the question.

Comment: Please update the question as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The default http Client has no timeout. You can create an explicit http.Client yourself and set the timeout:

```
var cl = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}

resp, err := cl.Do(req)

if err != nil {
    // err will be set on timeout
    return errors.Wrap(err, "http request error")
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

If the server does not answer any more in the middle of a request, you can handle the timeout.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: the timeout you're referring to works on a layer *above* TCP/IP, and covers not only the connection time but also the time to do the request (and fetch the server's response). It means that if you set it to, say, 3 seconds (as the OP wanted) and the *connection* will happen to complete in this time frame, the timeout will then have any possibility to reap the request in the middle of the actual data exchange.

Comment: To say that in other words: as I understood, the OP wanted to "fail fast" if the server appears to be dead—while having a more generous timeout (or none at all) for the request to it to proceed normaly in the opposite case.

Comment: This could be, but this was merely suggested within comments after I posted this answer. Perhaps the OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-default `http.Transport` with its `DialContext` field set to a function which uses a custom context with the properly configured timeout/deadline.  Another option is to use a custom `net.Dialer`.

Something like this:

```
cli := http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: func (ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
            dialer := net.Dialer{
                Timeout: 3 * time.Second,
            }
            return dialer.DialContext(ctx, network, address)
        },
    },
}

req, err := http.NewRequest(...)
resp, err := cli.Do(req)
```

Note that as per the `net.Dialer`'s docs the context passed to its `DialContext` might trump the timeout set on the dialer itself—this is
exactly what we need: the dialer's `Timeout` field controls exactly the
"dialing" (TCP connection establishment) while you might also arm your
HTTP request with a context (using `http.Request.WithContext`) controlling
the timeout of the whole request, and also be able to cancel it at any time (including the dialing step).

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/tO058F954Cu).

Answer (score 1):

The Transport @kostix refers to is definitely what you're looking for in this case.  Transports as well as Clients are safe for concurrent use as well.  But please [read about the Transport](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go) (and I also advise reading about the Client as well) as there are a number of different ways to affect how you handle idle connections, not just the pre-mentioned DialContext.

As you may want to set your `ResponseHeaderTimeout`:

> ResponseHeaderTimeout, if non-zero, specifies the amount of
>     time to wait for a server's response headers after fully
>     writing the request (including its body, if any). This
>     time does not include the time to read the response body.

Or, if you are using a secure connection, you may want to set your `TLSHandshakeTimeout`:

> TLSHandshakeTimeout specifies the maximum amount of time waiting to
>     wait for a TLS handshake. Zero means no timeout.

For readability and maintainability, I suggest also maybe creating a function to build your Client, something along the lines of:

```
func buildClient(timeout time.Duration) *http.Client {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        IdleConnTimeout:       timeout,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: timeout,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   timeout,
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
        Timeout:   timeout,
    }
    return client
}
```

Comment: Good tips, but the `IdleConnTimeout` appears to be offbeat here: it controls for how long a successfully established TCP connection will remain live *after the request which created it has completed* (and both sides during it agreed to keep the connection alive). A good think to tinker with for the case of many client requests going to the same server in a quick succession, but I think this has little to do with the OP's situation, so it's better not to confuse them more that they already are ;-)

Comment: @kostix some of the items listed in the example which were not directly spoke of I put in for illustrative purposes, to show the OP there are a number of items within the Transport documentation to familiarize themselves with.